# Could precipitation from steam cause a light switch to short circuit?

Tags: switch

Our bathroom isn't properly ventilated and so gets really steamy. Last night after my partner had a shower I turned the light on only to be electrocuted by the switch and have the light bulb blow. Is it possible that water got into either the switch or the light socket? And if it is how do we stop it?

The house is at least 80 years old and its clear there is quite a bit of water damage to the bathroom.

Comment: You'll really want to put a GFCI breaker on that bathroom circuit.  That's code for new construction, with modern switches... Certainly is a good idea on old work without grounds.

Comment: You might want to edit your post: you got *shocked*; "electrocuted" means shocked dead.

Answer (score 1):

You should move that switch to the outside of the bathroom or install a pull cord switch.  You are correct that water will get into both and I really would not be using that switch again.

Comment: Agreed, OP came quite close to being killed, but for a little more conductivity.  This is worse than wetness.  Switch outside is a great deal, we have that in our 90 year old place.

Comment: I wouldn't use an outside switch if you can help it.  It would look terrible and it's still not designed to be used in a bathroom.  Assuming your bathroom is upstairs, it would not be too much trouble to trace the wires in the attic and fit a pull cord switch.  You could leave the old switch there if you wanted (I wouldn't).  Just add a junction box and run a new wire to the pull switch.  Would take about half an hour.  Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid rewiring, get a GFCI switch, or you could get an outdoor switch for use in a wet environment.